# React-query + Nextjs using hydration config for SSR doesn't use cached results and always have to wait fetch again

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, react-query, hydration

I'm trying to use react-query on my nextjs app with SSR/SSG and tried a lot of tutorials. Took `hydration` config because it seems better than `initialData` approach.

Following react-query guide: https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/ssr you just have to wrap the app on `QueryClientProvider` and `Hydrate` components passing a prop to each one.

```
    const App = ({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) => {
      const [queryClient] = useState(
        () => new QueryClient({ defaultOptions: { queries: { staleTime: 30 * 1000 } } })
      )

      return (
        <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
          <Hydrate state={pageProps.dehydratedState}>
            <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen={false} />
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
              <CssBaseline />
              <Component {...pageProps} />
            </ThemeProvider>
          </Hydrate>
        </QueryClientProvider>
      )
    }

    export default App
```

To start fetching data with react-query on `getServerSideProps/getStaticProps` you just instance a new `queryClient`, execute `prefetchQuery` and set a prop with `dehydrate(queryClient)`.

```
    export async function getStaticProps() {
      const queryClient = new QueryClient()
      await queryClient.prefetchQuery<Todo[]>('todos', fetchTodos)

      return {
        props: {
          dehydratedState: dehydrate(queryClient),
        },
      }
    }

    const Home: NextPage = () => {
      const { data, isLoading } = useQuery<Todo[]>('todos', fetchTodos)
      console.log(isLoading)

      if (isLoading) return <h1>Loading...</h1>
```

I've created a small api that return same data as https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos but with a `setTimeout` of 3 seconds. The problem is that everytime i reload or move from one page to another using `next/link`, it takes 3 seconds to load the page. It indicates that react-query cache is not being used.

Tried moving the queryClient instance outside getServerSideProps.

Tried adding `staleTime` to all queries as my config shows above.

Only solution I've found was:

```
    export const queryClient = new QueryClient()

    export async function getStaticProps() {
      if (!queryClient.getQueryData('todos')) {
        await queryClient.prefetchQuery<Todo[]>('todos', fetchTodos)
      }

      return {
        props: {
          dehydratedState: dehydrate(queryClient),
        },
      }
    }
```

But there is no one talking about it and feels like i'm doing it wrong.

This is my network tab when moving to another page and going back before 30 seconds of my `staleTime` config and queryClient instanced outside gssp:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9f0ZG.png)

Answer (score 4):

if you're creating the queryClient outside of `getStaticProps`, you're sharing it between requests and users. That might be what you want, but it also might not be what you want. I am not sure what the lifetime of a `QueryClient` is that gets created outside of `getStaticProps` though.

Instead of doing the `if` check, you can also pass a `staleTime` to `prefetchQuery`. If data exists in the cache, it will be returned, otherwise, new data will be fetched:

```
await queryClient.prefetchQuery<Todo[]>('todos', fetchTodos, { staleTime: 1000 * 60 * 10 })
```

There is also the idea to newly create the cache inside `getStaticProps` / `getServerSideProps`, but prefill it with data from an external store, e.g. a `redis` cache. Have a look at this discussion: https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query/discussions/3563

Comment: "Instead of doing the if check, you can also pass a staleTime to prefetchQuery. If data exists in the cache, it will be returned, otherwise, new data will be fetched". 
Setting the staleTime locally worked, but only if creating queryClient outside the getServerSideProps. I don't understand why

Comment: it is two separate problems. creating the query client inside the function means there won't be data in the cache to re-use. a new client means a new, empty cache.

Comment: any solution, I'm also having this problem??

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution for myself to this problem and I found this [work around](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/32243#discussioncomment-1767080). It was mentioned in this [post](https://dev.to/arianhamdi/react-query-v4-ssr-in-next-js-2ojj#with-csr).
Basically, it check where the request come from. If it's from a client side request, getServerSideProps will return an empty object.

```
export const hasNavigationCSR = (next) => async (ctx) => {
  if (ctx.req.url?.startsWith('/_next')) {
    return {
      props: {},
    };
  }
  return next?.(ctx);
};
```

Then,

```
export const getServerSideProps = hasNavigationCSR(async (ctx) => {
  const queryClient = new QueryClient()
  if (!queryClient.getQueryData('todos')) {
    await queryClient.prefetchQuery<Todo[]>('todos', fetchTodos)
  }

  return {
    props: {
      dehydratedState: dehydrate(queryClient),
    },
  }
});
```